# Can I replace p6ke110a with 1N4148 in my smps circuit

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I am building an smps circuit using TNY280. I would like to know if I can use 1N4148 in place of p6ke110a to protect TNY280 from flyback voltage from transformer as they both have almost same specs

Comment: What lead you to the conclusion that 1N4148 was a suitable candidate?

Answer (score 6):

Without a schematic or circuit drawing, I can only compare spec to spec and part to part.

The P6KE110A is a transient voltage supressor (TVS) diode rated at 116V breakdown, 152V clamping and 600W (peak pulse) dissipation. A 1N4148 is a general-purpose diode rated at 100V - it is not a TVS and is not intended for repetitive high-voltage breakdowns. They most certainly do not have the same specs, and as such should not be swapped.

According to ON Semi, the P6KE110A is obsolete. This is presumably why you are looking for an alternate part. Please limit your choices to TVS diodes with comparable power dissipation and clamp voltages and steer clear of general-purpose diodes for this swap.